# Infinite loop when confirm order

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, checkout-page

my site is www.e-miko.com and when:

1. I add a product to the cart
2. go to the checkout page
3. select payment method (cash delivery)
4. click the button confirm

I have a loop and I can't continue...

If I inspect the code I see these errors
[image: errors]

Comment: Debugging JS/CSS is a task that can
best be done on site and not a good question for the StackExchange Q&A. However, if you
want to try your luck, please provide as much information as possible: Which theme are you
using? Were there any modifications to the theme? Did it work correctly before and if so,
what has been changed (for example installed extensions)? Do not just drop a URL - this can
help to provide context but eventually you will fix your problem and the question remains
without value for future visitors.

Comment: your checkout has been customization.it may be created issue as per as my concept

Comment: I need italian language. what can I do to fix it?

Comment: The answer from Siarhey Uchukhlebau should point you in the right direction. Try to open the URLs from the console in your browser or use the "network" console to inspect the response, you might see an error message there. Additionally you should inspect the error logs of Magento and the web server.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the browser console your request returns 400 error with corresponding html inside:

[image: response]

But Magento expect to receive a JSON in response (Magento try to parse html like JSON). You should debug why the server returns 400.